# post data from angular(v 5) to api's db using interface

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular5

I am making a crud operation in angular(v 5) with within node app.
I have successfully getting data in my view . but i am having problem with my post script with angular.

[file structure of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzF2n.png)

---

my app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  // <-- #1 import module
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  // { path: '/', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

my auth.ts file

```
export interface Auth {
    name : string
}
```

---

my auth.services.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Auth } from './auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()





export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  // dataUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  dataGet = 'http://localhost:3000/user/get';

  dataPost = 'http://localhost:3000/user/post';

  getData(): Observable<Auth[]> {
    return this.http.get<Auth[]>(this.dataGet);
  }

  postData(): Observable<Auth[]> {
    return this.http.post<Auth[]>(this.dataPost,{headers: Headers});
  }

}
```

---

my register.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Auth } from '../../services/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public auths = [];


  model = {
    name: ""
  }

  constructor(private _authService : AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.postData()
    .subscribe(data => this.auths = data );
  }

}
```

---

my register.component.html file

```
<form (ngSubmit)="(onSubmit)">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName1">Name address</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="NameHelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"> -->
</form
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: define `onSubmit` method in your `.ts` file as you have used it in `ngsubmit` in the HTML file.

Comment: @aimprogman, i am unable to store data from front end(register.component.html) to API.

Comment: I cant see you passing any data to api.

Comment: you are calling api directly on `ngOnInit` however no data is being passed to api.

Comment: @Rahul, I made changes as per laiso(person answered) , and it is working, is it the same thing , you are telling me to do?

Comment: @ManishVashisth yes exactly..u were not passing data to your api...so https://stackoverflow.com/a/49249269/1608841 answer make sense !

Answer (score 2):

You should update your `AuthService.postData()` method like this:

```
postData(data): Observable<Auth[]> {
  return this.http.post<Auth[]>(this.dataPost, data, {headers: Headers});
}
```

In your `register.component.html` file, add the submit handler:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="(onSubmit)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName1">Name address</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="NameHelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Notice that I have edited the `[(ngModel)]="model.name"`.

Then, update the `register.component.ts` file like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public auths = [];

  model = {
    name: ""
  }

  constructor(private _authService : AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // remove the logic here
  }

  // add this method - I moved the logic you wrote inside the ngOnInit method here
  submit() {
    this._authService.postData(this.model)
    .subscribe(data => this.auths = data );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks , It works on putting in auth.service.ts the following code.

  postData(data): Observable<Auth[]> {
    return this.http.post<Auth[]>(this.dataPost, data);
  }
instead of 
postData(data): Observable<Auth[]> {
  return this.http.post<Auth[]>(this.dataPost, data, {headers: Headers});
}

Comment: You're welcome! :) so don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your service auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Auth } from './auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  // dataUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  dataGet = 'http://localhost:3000/user/get';

  dataPost = 'http://localhost:3000/user/post';

  getData(): Observable<Auth[]> {
    return this.http.get<Auth[]>(this.dataGet);
  }

  postData(data){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    headers.append('Content-Type' : 'application/json'); 

    return this.http.post(this.dataPost,data,{headers: headers });
  }

}
```

in your component register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Auth } from '../../services/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
   auths:any = [];



    name:string ="";


  constructor(private _authService : AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

 onSend(){
    this._authService.postData({name: this.name})
    .subscribe(data => this.auths = data );
  }

}
```

register.component.html

```
<form>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName1">Name address</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="NameHelp" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSend()">Submit</button>
  <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"> -->
</form
```

Comment: I am getting following error : - and In database ID is created but nothing else . 

ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(19,46): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: { new (init?: any): Headers; prototype: Headers; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type '{ new (init?: any): Headers; prototype: Headers; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.

Comment: @aimprogram,
if i remove {headers: Headers} in auth.service.ts then following error occures:-
ERROR in src/app/components/register/register.component.ts(26,24): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?..............

Comment: @aimprogram , Its working now, but there's some problem too, Kindly look if its just random or my editor .
https://imgur.com/a/QXgba

Comment: @ManishVashisth edited answer  auths:any = [], can you show me what you recieve from server,  object or array? I want to know type of data?

Comment: onSend(){
    this._authService.postData({name: this.name})
    .subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
  }

Comment: @aimprogram , Thanks . Its working now without any error. 
your edited answer is perfect. Thanks again for help

Comment: @ManishVashisth You're welcome! :) so don't forget to upvote and accept the answer